# Autofac error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.0.0,...' My project is Owin WebApi2 SelfHost

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac, owin, self-hosting

I have a simple project which uses  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost.  It is a Owin self hosted WebApi 2 project.The project is pretty much similar to:-

https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication

The only difference I have is my Security module is in separate Assembly (everything similar to above project). I use Autofac to resolve my dependencies.

This project worked when there's no Autofac. But once I am trying to setup my project with the corresponding security modules and Autofac all I am facing is this error:-

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

My configuration is very much inspired from this thread:-

[Dependency injection not working with Owin self-hosted Web Api 2 and Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177734/dependency-injection-not-working-with-owin-self-hosted-web-api-2-and-autofac)

Moreover, I found someone else struggled with this dependency bug of Autofac and was able to get similar issue resolved by re-installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost:

[GlobalConfiguration.Configure() not present after Web API 2 and .NET 4.5.1 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226715/globalconfiguration-configure-not-present-after-web-api-2-and-net-4-5-1-migra)

But this doesn't work for me I don't know why. I've tried re-installing everything from scratch also doesn't help. Besides the fact that Autofac has several permission issues while re-installing as well.

Anybody has any experience with this error? please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I managed to fix this dependency issue with help from comment by @user998660 in [above thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629279/4202721).

What I did is:

- I right clicked the assembly System.Web.Http in my Project's references.
- I noticed that the version of assembly referenced by my project is `5.2.3.0`
- From the error above I know that Autofac is trying to reference System.Web.Http version `5.2.0.0`. I needed a means to tell my app to use the newer version `5.2.3.0` instead of `5.2.0.0`.

This is what I needed to add to my Web.config's `<assemblyBinding>` section:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I can confirm that fixed the issue for me too

Comment: this helped me as well. you should have marked this as answer.

Comment: All I had to do was update the `<bindingRedirect ... />` element to what @amitthk posted. Thanks!

Comment: If you use Nuget Package Manager, it will fix it for you when installing the WebApi package again.

Answer (score 1):

Open managed nuget packages for solution, and install the latest Microsoft Asp.net Web Api 2.2  and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some times, the .nuget restore could give an issue.. though after successful checkin, setting disableSourceControlIntegration to false in .nuget.config file, would resolve this issue.
 add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="false"