# Owin Testing (Self hosting) not registering web api routes when using DI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor, owin, asp.net-web-api-routing, self-hosting

I am trying to implement [Microsoft.Owin.Testing/3.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Testing/3.0.1) for WebApi 2 integration tests. Everything works fine except when I add [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). The routes are not recognized or I am unable to register them properly. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with api controller dependency injection that is not used when testing.

My values api controller

```
 [RoutePrefix("api")]
        public class ValuesApiController : ApiController
        {
            private readonly ValuesControllerService _valuesControllerService;

            public ValuesApiController(ValuesControllerService valuesControllerService)
            {
                _valuesControllerService = valuesControllerService;
            }

            // GET api/values
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("values")]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
            {
                if (_valuesControllerService == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("valuesControllerService");

                return Ok(new[] { "value1", "value2" });
            }
        }
```

I am using Castle Windsor to resolve API Controllers using ([source](https://github.com/jvanderbiest/OwinTestingWebApi/tree/master/OwinTestingWebApi/IoC)):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(_container));
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(_container));
```

I'm registering my WebApi routes in Global.asax so it is registered properly when running the application (and not the tests).

```
public class WebApiApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
```

When testing, I call the registration after Startup. Here is a sample test which I use ([test source](https://github.com/jvanderbiest/OwinTestingWebApi/blob/master/OwinTestingWebApi.Tests/Integration/ValuesControllerTests.cs)):

```
[Test]
        public async void GetValueTestForStartup1()
        {
            using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup1>())
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient(server.Handler))
                {
                    var request = await client.GetAsync(_url);

                    Assert.IsTrue(request.IsSuccessStatusCode);
                }
            }
        }
```

And here are some Startup implementations I tried:

```
internal class Startup1
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                new Startup().ConfigureForIntegrationTests(app, x => x.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new SingletonEqualizer()));
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new TestWebApiResolver());
                GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            }
        }
```

> 404 when executing a request

```
internal class Startup2
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        new Startup().ConfigureForIntegrationTests(app, x => x.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new SingletonEqualizer()));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : This method cannot be called during
>   the application's pre-start initialization phase.

```
internal class Startup3
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            new Startup().ConfigureForIntegrationTests(app, y => y.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new SingletonEqualizer()));
            // Web API routes

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new TestWebApiResolver());
        }
    }
```

> 500 Internal Server error (probably because there is no parameterless
>   constructor found).

Complete sourceproject is located here:
https://github.com/jvanderbiest/OwinTestingWebApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177734/dependency-injection-not-working-with-owin-self-hosted-web-api-2-and-autofac) about AutoFac. I must have looked over that [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177734/dependency-injection-not-working-with-owin-self-hosted-web-api-2-and-autofac?answertab=votes#tab-top) but the key to all of this is to register everything with your own `HttpConfiguration` instead of using the `GlobalConfiguration` object.

I have updated the [github code](https://github.com/jvanderbiest/OwinTestingWebApi/commit/0bed2f760c2109af65ae0fbae600455ee9697f4d) so the test is working fine now!